# Besides Whiterun, what is a good starting city for a new character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm starting my third character, and looking for a change of pace.

I know that the enemy level scaling works differently than in Oblivion - there are real dangers lurking in the wilderness for a low level character, since not everything is scaled down to your level.

Other than Whiterun, which cities reachable by carriage offer:

- A surrounding wilderness free of Sabre Cats, Bears, Frost Trolls and the like
- Some nearby camps/dungeons accessible to characters below level 10
- More than one side quest to pursue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I walked to Falkreath with a lvl 1 character, then with about a lvl 5 went to Markarth. The only time I had problems was attacking a fort on the way to Markarth, the forts and villages were to high a lvl, but then I just skipped them and did quests in Markarth. Didn't touch Whiterun till lvl 20.

From what I've seen most cities are scaled per lvl, the surroundings might not be fully scaling but you can avoid things that'll kill you.

To answer your specific questions:

```
A surrounding wilderness free of Sabre Cats, Bears, Frost Trolls and the like
```

Falkreath has none of those

```
Some nearby camps/dungeons accessible to characters below level 10
```

Falkreath as well has about 5+ dungeons you can walk to, on the way to it from the starting area you run across some dungeons you can do at lvl 1-2

Markarth has a number of near by areas but seems to be more for a bit higher then lvl 1 or 2

```
More than one side quest to pursue
```

Falkreath has bout 5-7 side quests in the town, depends on how much follow up you do with them.

Markarth has a lot of side quests

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the beginning at Helgen, you choose between going with the Stormcloak or Imperial, and then it says to join the Immperial Legion or Stormcloacks.  I think once you get to the Whiterun stables, travel to either Solitude or Windhelm and those will be a good starting city.  An Imperial Legion soldier suggests visiting these cities as well.

Answer (score -1):

I like starting at Morthal doing the "Laid to rest" quest.  The hold I stay away from is Dawnstar (boring) but the quick silver mine can be profitable.  I've started three characters, one in Whiterun, then Morthal and right now it's Riften because my lizard likes swamps.  Tread carefully: in the rift there are trolls, heaps of bears, and bandits.  I've also seen one troll and two bears in Falkreath.

Comment: Some puctuation would help a lot!